# Как загрузить изображение в бд php

Tags: php

Не могу загрузить изображение в БД. Выдает ошибку "Необходимо загрузить изображение", то есть он уже выдает ошибку в первом условии следующего кода:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['img_user'])) {
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_user']['tmp_name'], 'img/'.$_FILES['img_user']['name'])){
        exit("Не удалось загрузить изображение");
    }
    $img_src = 'img/'.$_FILES['img_user']['name'];
}

else{
    exit("Необходимо загрузить изображение");
}
```

Форма

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="?option=reg">
  <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 0;">
  <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for='img_user'>Ваше фото:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
  <input type='file' name='img_user' class='form-control' placeholder="Выберите фотографию" id='img_user'>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно указать в теге `form` атрибут [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/enctype):

```
<form action="handler.php"
   enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

без него отправка файлов не произойдет

Comment: Это не помогает, к сожалению